# Need Help Using @HTML.Label

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

Given the admittedly simple class below:

```
public class BallPointPen
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
}

public enum Color
{
    Black,
    Gold,
    Silver    
}
```

I want to generate ASP.NET HTML elements similar to the following:

```
@model BallPointPen
<label for="black">Black</label>
input type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="Black"><br>
<label for="gold">Gold</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="gold" value="Gold"><br>
<label for="silver">Silver</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="other" value="Silver"><br>
```

but using Razor @Html.Label and @Html.Radiobutton helpers.  My problem is that using the @Html.Label helper, it generates for=propertyname, whereas I need it to generate for=radiobuttonid.  If there's an overload that lets me specify that, I haven't found it on Google, hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use the html attributes overload to set them?

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.color, new { @for = "gold" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.color, new { id = "gold" })
```

Comment: Well, that's why I asked.  I'm new at this, and the tutorials I've been following don't address this.  But another question: why do you have @for and not @id?

Comment: You can omit the @ for the for attribute in the label. You only need that for reserved words (like "class"). @TheOldCrab the second argument is setting HTML attributes, so he's setting  the for attribute on the label that gets generated.

Comment: @TheOldCrab I think I'm correct in saying that the last overload of the helpers always accepts an anonymous object which can be used to set attributes on the html element manually.